# Simulink/Matlab Error: "Derivative of state '1' in block 'project/Subsystem/Transfer Fcn' at time 2.084275 is not finite...."

Tags: matlab, simulink

[I keep getting these errors for this system.
For the signal generator, the settings are 0.5 Amplitude, 0.1Hz frequency, and square wave input.
For the PID, I've set it to be around 10% overshoot.
Stop time: 20s
Solver Selection type set to Fixed-step and Fixed-step size to 00.01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOkeZ.png)

[This is the subsystem. The image below is meant to be -14/s+14 not +ve 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZdgG.png)

Error: "An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was terminated
Caused by:
Derivative of state '1' in block 'project/Subsystem/Transfer Fcn' at time 3.3375 is not finite. The simulation will be stopped. There may be a singularity in the solution.  If not, try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error tolerances)"

Comment: There may be a singularity. Your code may generate infinite values (e.g. if you generated an unstable closed loop system), or your input may generate infinite/nan values. Recheck your math, and recheck your inputs.